# PHPUnit tutorial? Or more general - unit testing tutorial worth recommending?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm looking for a tutorial which explains **why** and **how** to write useful unit tests. Specifically I'm interested in PHPUnit, however any more general might be a good one to explain that. Please note that *I'm not looking for technical information on how to use PHPunit* - rather the tutorial on the way of thinking!

Comment: I've been watching this thread for days, as this is a topic I'm very intrested in. Sad to see lack of replies ... there are so many differing opinions I expected a real bun fight.

For example, I've seen a guy giving a talk saying he hated mocks - his general feeling was that most of the time he felt like you were testing the mock, not the code.  Come on! Argue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know of a tutorial. But I can give you my views from what I have gathered over the years.

Writing UnitTests are meant to test the functionality of the application. Thus given this say you write a core class that has 3 functions, getData setData and displaydata (just thinking off the top of my head). You want to write a unit case that goes in set's a Data (you pass in good data and bad data because it is important to know that it errors properly). Then you check the setData, either via a DB call or with the same class using the getData, and you try and get the data with bad data, good data etc. Make sure this handles that properly. Then you write the display data and rinse and repeat.

Basically you want to test that the core class (or application classes) handles data properly (errors / good data etc). If all of the tests come out clean then you can move up and write a test for other classes that use that core class. But there is no point to moving on if your core class does not / has not pass tests or else debugging becomes a night mare. I have never really looked into PHP Unit test, I used to just write all mine given Use Case Scenarios (IE: How the functions would be used / implemented). This is a general way of thinking what to write up a test-case for.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a presentation covering just that as an intro.  Hopefully it functions without speaker notes:
http://www.scribd.com/full/34941838?access_key=key-1u9c5kmupy1889f4o6tv
(this is actually still an early revision, any feedback you could give me would be valued :)

It borrows heavily from the book "**xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code**"
http://rcm.amazon.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=alex010-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&m=amazon&f=ifr&md=10FE9736YVPPT7A0FBG2&asins=0131495054"

Also look at the presentations by **Sebastian Bergmann** the creator of PHPUnit
http://talks.php.net/index.php/Testing

If you can afford the book, it would count as my number one recommendation on learning about Unit testing thought patterns.

Finally (or perhaps as an after thought) your next steps in getting up to 'professional standards' in QA would benefit by going through the

**American Society for Quality:** http://www.asq.org/

With the purchase of a membership (from about $50 to $150 USD), you can sign up for courses and get certified in QA.

Furthermore, their study course materials (cost unknown) can be sent to your workplace for you to self-study, write a test, get certified and train others in QA.

Really hope that helps. 
- Alex

Answer (score 1):

Just found easy to start tutorial about unit testing with php, that uses SimpleTest instead of PHPUnit : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/the-newbies-guide-to-test-driven-development/

Answer (score 0):

The official site of PhpUnit is also having good examples and all WHYs and HOWs.

Have a look at [it](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/automating-tests.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm just beginning to learn how to use TDD properly and I'm currently using PHPUnit. I can't overstate enough how the work of Uncle Bob ([Robert C. Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin)) has helped me. I'm fortunate enough to have a company that has afforded the videos. But his work with 'Clean Code' is amazing.

In the videos he uses a 'cap' to switch between the different stages of TDD (Red > Green > Refactor) and describes the stages in excellent detail. I'm also using [TDD Kata's](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) to improve my PHP and TDD mind-set skills. I believe that the mindset isn't something that coders are used to. Because you code to fix a failing test, you think *small* rather than big. Segregating the specific task you're doing to the code stops you from straying too far. At a given moment you are either coding to pass a test, passing a test, or refactoring your code - never anywhere in between. And because it is small iterations, I believe that sits better with the developer - it does with me!

I should stress that I'm an amateur developer and I've only just started out (indeed this is my first post!). In my opinion the test first approach works really well. It forces you to write modular code, because it has to for testing. You, in turn, write code that adheres to SOLID principles.

Go easy with me. I'm still learning :)